# IDEA GWT compiler and backend issue

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

My project uses GWT. Our team write code under IDEA  And every time when I change something on backend I have to recompile both GWT and server side code to be putted on artifact folder. It is not very good situation. So I want to know if it is possible to setup project/IDEA/GWT in such way that we would not need to recompile GWT every time regardless of whether we have changed GWT or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using GWT with Intellij IDEA as well.

For server side changes, we have to restart the backend server in IDEA, but we don't have to recompile GWT code.

You can keep the GWT code server running all the time (in super mode):

[image: IDEA Run Configuration]

And the URL to check is http://127.0.0.1:9876/, and then put the "Dev Mode On" button in your bookmark bar.

[image: Super Mode Page]

To enable latest code, you only need to click this button when the application page is opened. It will apply the latest GWT code into your application page, which is also pretty fast.

Comment: Any reason you don't use `-launcherDir` with CodeServer to get compile-on-load?

Comment: Didn't use that before, will have a look. Thank you @ThomasBroyer for the hint.